# How to plot several sections side by side

Tags: python, matlab, plot, plotmatrix

I have 14 soundings with 213 points each ( matrix 213x14) 
I would like to plot each column side by side, so I could see a Pseudo 2D section, how can I plot that?
Y-axis is always the same, that is, the depth, so in the x-axis, I would like to have the 14 columns separated by a distance of 10
This is what I have tried:

```
mrec = importdata('mrec.csv')
[nmrec,nsoundings] = size(mrec)
x = [0:10:130]
for loc = 1:nsoundings
    xi = x(loc)*ones(nmrec,1)
    plot(xi,mrec(:,loc))
    hold on
end
hold off
```

And this is what I got

[image]

Since I don't know how to put my Z(depth) and x(position) at the same time, I'm not able to get what I want.
I would like to have the 14 graphs like this in the picture below, side by side, at the x position, so my x-axis should be conductivity[S/m] and position[m]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What are you *specifically* stuck on? What does your [mcve] look like? Is something unclear in the `plot`/`subplot`/`linkaxes`/... documentation or do you not know certain functions exist? Help us help you, this is too vague

Comment: @Wolfie I have updated my question, maybe now is clearly

Comment: Mm not really, because we have zero visibility of "mrec.csv" it's impossible for us to know how your vertical lines plot (top figure) should be a series of plots with additional x axis data (bottom figure). This is why a [mcve] is so valuable, create some example data which we can see, which perhaps demonstrates what you want for two lines. Even if you draw the example in paint or plot things seperately so we can see how real data maps onto your expectations. This makes the problem clear, answering easier and more relevant, and you can easily scale the solution back up to your original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think placing 14 plots side by side would really work, but you can do something like this:

```
M = 5; % Number of plots
for k = 1:M
    % Create some data
    N = randi([30 100]);
    y = linspace(0,-N,100);
    x = cumsum(rand(1,100));

    % Side by side plots
    subplot(1,M,k);
    semilogx(x,y, '.');
    ax(k) = gca;

    % Handle x-axis labels
    str = sprintf("(S/m)\nx = %d m", k*10);
    xlabel(str)
end

% Synchronize y axes
ax(1).YLabel.String = "z(m)";
set(ax(2:end), 'YTickLabel', [])
linkaxes(ax, 'y')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Is not what I really want, but works fine =)